# In Twitter API, how to find intermediary retweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to find through which users some tweets are retweeted.

For instance, I have a tweet by a user, which happens the be a retweet. I want to know who the user retweeted it from. I found this:

```
tweet.retweeted_status.user.screen_name
```

Which seems to do the job... but then, I find out that its gives me the name of the tweet's original creator, and not the name of the potential intermediary user...

According to the Twitter API documentation:

> Retweets can be distinguished from typical Tweets by the existence of
>   a retweeted_status attribute. This attribute contains a representation
>   of the original Tweet that was retweeted. Note that retweets of
>   retweets do not show representations of the intermediary retweet, but
>   only the original tweet.

In this simple chain of retweets:

> Original author of tweet A -> Intermediary user who retweeted A-> End user who retweeted A.

When I'm looking at the a tweet A retweeted by the end user, how can I get the name of the intermediary user, instead of the original user?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. Twitter doesn't appear to expose this information anywhere -- it's not shown on the web site either. (It may not even be recorded by Twitter.)